# Cookies with string containing ;

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

So I'm using cookies for my website (big surprise ;-) ), but what might be surprising is that I for some reason (don't ask me why) store some `css` style values in the cookie, which is all fine and dandy until you add a `;` in there which is not supposed to be there.

So the cookie I've stored looks like this:

```
token=9d133691-a955-4980-bf1d-9492d3c64026; 
user=2601; 
config=JSON"{
    "socketAddress":"string",
    ... 
    bunch more values
    ...
    "views":[{
        "showInMenu":true,
        "route":"Opgave Liste",
        "routeParameters":{"afdeling":true},
        "viewFunctions":{
            "itemList":{
                "css":{
                    "class":"bold",
                    "conditional":{
                        "condition":"[REG.TASK] === 'off'",
                        "false":{
                            "style":"background:red;"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}";
```

and the way I get the cookie is like this:

```
    <script>
        function readCookie(){
            var cookie = document.cookie;
            console.info('base cookie : ', cookie);
        }
        readCookie();
    </script>
```

the result i get is the right cookie, it however is cut right after `background:red`. As I mentioned earlier I know why, my question is, is there a way to prevent this and still have the `;` in the string. is there some kind of escape character like you have in string: ie. `\"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `encodeURIComponent(css)` before doing the JSON stringification, and then using `decodeURIComponent` in order to get the real value.

For example:

```
{
    "style": encodeURIComponent("background:red;")
}
```

(You can/should automate this process with utility functions).